# Perl script to access all user account directories on Linux server

Tags: linux, perl, accounts

I have a dedicated Linux web server with many user accounts on it.  The user accounts are all  located in `/home/[userid]` directories.   I am able to create Perl scripts that run within each of my users’ accounts that can access files only within their own account, but now I need to create a script that can run “above” the users’ accounts and be able to access a file within any specified user’s account.

Currently, I have a script that uses `Net::FTP` to retrieve the needed file from each account so  I can extract the necessary data from it, but of course, it’s slow to FTP into every account. Since the accounts are merely directories on the server, I’m looking for a way to run a Perl script in a way that it can access each account directory and simply open the required file and return the requested data for the specified account.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? What issues are you running into when you try accessing the data from a locally run script? (i.e. running on the server)

Answer (score 2):

You should login as a user that has access to all the user directories (e.g. `root`). For security reasons, it might be safer to use `sftp` or some other encrypted connection.

Comment: @tchrist: I used "folder" because the question used it.

Comment: So it did.  I’ll fix that, too.